I dont understand @keydown event in Vue
App.vue
<template>
  <div class="container" @keydown="console.log('pressed')">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
</style>

I want on keydown to log ('pressed') to the console
The project has been created with npm create vue@latest. Everything was standard and nothing changed other than App.vue. No Vue Router involved.
No matter what I do the event won't fire. If I change the event to @clicked it works perfectly fine.

https://blog.boot.dev/javascript/vue-key-events/

Give a read to this one: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#key-modifiers Keydown is mostly Keyup but at a different time of the travel of the switch.

@keydown is meant to work as HTML's keydown event is used. Mostly meant for keyboard inputs in form elements. An element has to be in focus (clicked on) by the user, which is intuitive for form elements.

You may be encountering this issue because the @keydown event often fails to be raised by the div element itself unless it receives focus from the user. By default, only input, textarea, and select are focusable elements that can capture keyboard events.
Adding tabindex="0" makes the div focusable. Clicking on it or programmatically focusing on it will allow it to capture keyboard events.
<template>
  <div class="container" tabindex="0" @keydown="handleKeydown">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const handleKeydown = () => {
  console.log('pressed');
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>


You need to add a tabindex to the div, like this:
<div class="container" @keydown="console.log('pressed')" tabindex="0">

Read this: Keyboard-navigable JavaScript widgets
